# How to Add new Column From Frozen Tuple Map?

Tags: python, cassandra

I have a cassandra database table and it has a column as paramaters and its type:

```
parameters map<text, frozen<tuple<text, text, bigint, double, text>>>,
```

I am trying to create a pandas df from this cassandra table:

```
def read_measurement_data():
    query = "select * from measurement"
    return pd.DataFrame(list(session.execute(query)))

measurement_df = read_measurement_data()
```

And after creating measurement_df I need to extract a column from frozen tuple map its' name is Speed.

How can I add this new column?

Comment: I would recommend to use user-defined type instead of tuple - it will be more flexible

Comment: @AlexOtt I can not touch db side. It is predefined and can not change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with following way:

```
def add_column(row):

    xnhct1 = row['parameters'].get('speed')

    if xnhct1 is not None:
        return xnhct1[3]

    return 0

measurement_table['speed'] = measurement_table.apply(lambda row: add_column(row), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

the values of CQL's tuple types are returned as Python `tuple` type, so you just need to extract your data correctly, and access data in tuple by index. Something like this:

```py
rows = session.execute('SELECT parameters FROM test.p1')
for row in rows:
   print row.parameters.values()
```

I recommend first extract data from query, and only after that generate Pandas data frame